# Torch-Model deployed in AI-Platform generates "Prediction failed: unknown error."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-ml

I modified [this code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/pytorch/Text%20Classification%20Using%20PyTorch%20and%20CMLE.ipynb) to address my own image-based object detection problem using a yolo_v2 built in Pytorch (weight file is 192 mb).

Everything runs as it should locally, and I can deploy the model without errors using a similar command like in the previous Notebook: I use Python Version 3.5, and I remove `--framework='SCIKIT_LEARN'`, which otherwise would cause an error when creating the version. It deploys without making trouble also when using debug-logging.

Yet, when I try to predict, I receive this error:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: unknown error."
}
```

My preprocessor expects three inputs, one of which a GCS address to a stored image, the other two are indices I pass as strings, which get converted to integers internally. A request which locally does exactly what it should looks somewhat like this

```
    requests = {"filename" : "gs://bucket/imagepath.jpg", 
    "coordinateX": "100", "coordinateY": "100"}
```

I can import my custom model, run it, and receive the expected output.

Yet, following the structure of the Notebook above, after deploying the model and using JSON format to predict, it leads to the error as mentioned.

Also, using the console-based interface inserting this

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "filename": "gs://bucket/imagepath.jpg",
      "coordinateX": "100",
      "coordinateY": "100"}]}
```

leads to the same error.

I've seen people report similar errors, and for them trial & error regarding the exact formatting of the request helped. On the other hand, I'm out of ideas of the form I should bring my data into to make it work.

Comment: The sample you are adapting from is currently broken and is blocked by this GitHub issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/issues/410
Where people are experiencing model deployment errors. But sounds like yours deployed successfully. 

It could be a formatting error or you might not have permission to access that object on GCS. Do any errors on the log show up for this?

Comment: What error do you get when you include `framework='SCIKIT_LEARN'`. (PyTorch isn't yet officially supported on AI Platform prediction and the service might think your model is a TensorFlow model.